# Conventions for commenting/documenting .sql files

Tags: mysql, comment-conventions

How do you guys comment/document your .sql files?
Are there conventions similar to those of javadoc and the likes?
What is commonly done in large scale database-heavy applications like facebook, twitter, google....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no commenting conventions for SQL like Javadoc that I've seen.  This would be a great question to pose to the Doxygen people though.

On the other hand, several RDBMS allow this:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE table_name IS 'This is a comment';
COMMENT ON COLUMN table_name.column_name IS 'This is a great column';
```

This is more in keeping with the whole RDBMS philosophy - it's all about data.
I don't know of any system that will generate nice documentation with this though.  Also, I don't think this is standard yet.

I don't think MySQL does comments this way but Oracle and PostgreSQL do.

Comment: I admit I didn't know I could add comments to the actual tables and columns. Thanks for that info! That would make commenting the actual .sql file redundant, if that is where I create those comments.

Comment: @DudeOnRock I found on Google how you add comments in MySQL: when you define columns with DDL at the end of the column definition add COMMENT 'This is a great column!'.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is that I've mostly stopped commenting as the comments get out of date and can then be misleading and worse than none.

I now try to make my objects (tables, columns, stored procedures, etc.) names as meaningful as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard or tool.  But I use a comment block at the head and sometimes explain complex clauses